# Column Values Based On Another Column Values

Tags: mysql

I have this data in my table '**application_form**', i was facing problem in fetching value based on `class1_status` and `class2_status` column.
Previously client requirement was to show all data with the values present in data table.

Now, requirement changed slightly and they want

1. `class1_update_date` values only if `class1_status` is '`completed`' and `null` for rest of the status.
2. `class2_update_date` values only if `class2_status` is '`completed`' and `null` for rest of the status.

Here is my table structure. Data is dummy.

```
Sno | class1_update_date | class2_update_date | class1_status | class2_status
1       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      completed       pending
2       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      pending         pending
3       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      in progress     pending 
4       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      pending         pending
5       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      pending         pending
6       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      in progress     pending         
7       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      completed       completed
8       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      in progress     pending         
9       10-01-2004              10-01-2006      completed       completed
10      10-01-2004              10-01-2006      in progress     pending
```

This is a simple query which was written before. Now, i am not getting what to give condition in place of column name to get desired output.

```
    SELECT class1_update_date, class2_update_date, class1_status, class2_status 
    FROM application_form;
```

Since, i am not much good at SQL query. So, i thought to ask question regarding this condition.

**Expected Output.**

```
Sno | class1_update_date | class2_update_date | class1_status | class2_status
1      10-01-2004                               completed       pending
2                                               pending         pending
3                                               in progress     pending 
4                                               pending         pending
5                                               pending         pending
6                                               in progress     pending         
7       10-01-2004          10-01-2006          completed       completed
8                                               in progress     pending         
9       10-01-2004          10-01-2006          completed       completed
10                                              in progress     pending
```

I was trying and searched question too, but was not able to start also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `case` statement like this:

```
SELECT case when class1_status = 'completed' then class1_update_date else null end as class1_update_date,
       case when class2_status = 'completed' then class2_update_date else null end as class2_update_date,
       class1_status, class2_status 
FROM application_form
```

You don't need any condition since you want to select all records, the `case` statement checks is status is completed than put the value, if not put `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using MySQL's `if` function:

```
select
    if (class1_status = 'completed', class1_update_date, null) as class1_update_date
    , if (class2_status = 'completed', class2_update_date, null) as class2_update_date
    , class1_status
    , class2_status
from application_form
```